# WAP in java to create a matrix of alphabets like

Tags: java

WAP in java to create a matrix like

```
   0 1 2 3 4
0  A B C D E
1  F G H I J
2  K L M N O
3  P Q R S T
4  U V W X Y
```

Comment: no idea what you are asking

Comment: We have to create a matrix in alphabetic order which is of size 5X5

Comment: Do you need to actually encode the text `Q/Z`, or can you use _either_ letter there?

Comment: @ShivamSharma Have you tried anything? Or what is your actual question?

Comment: What does `WAP` mean?

Comment: We actually need Q/Z ... but for sake of simplicity I eliminated that. Do you have a way to get them both  @Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: write a program

Comment: @ShivamSharma That kind of question is off-topic here. This is not a code-writing service, and the person who answered your question should not have done so.

Comment: @4castle Actually, I think the question was completely clear, but perhaps it did merit to be closed for lack of effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to iterate over a 2D array of characters, filling it with the letters of the alphabet contained in a string:

```
char[][] letters = new char[5][5];
String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY";

for (int i=0; i < letters.length; ++i) {
    for (int j=0; j < letters[i].length; ++j) {
        letters[i][j] = alphabet.charAt(i*letters.length + j);
    }
}
```

If you also want to have `Q/Z` in place of the letter `Q`, you can slightly modify the code as follows:

```
String[][] letters = new String[5][5];
String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY";

for (int i=0; i < letters.length; ++i) {
    for (int j=0; j < letters[i].length; ++j) {
        char letter = alphabet.charAt(i*letters.length + j);
        if (letter == 'Q') {
            letters[i][j] = letter + "/Z";
        }
        else {
            letters[i][j] = String.valueOf(letter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ".valueOf " what is does ?

Comment: This converts a single character into a string.  We need to use an array of strings, because you want to encode the text `Q/Z` into a single cell, hence we can't use primitive characters.